# Funcion regex separados por comas en JS una o mas veces

Tags: javascript, regex, lógica

Tengo esta funcion regex ^([0-9]+.([0-9]{2})). pero me gustaria que se pueda digitar los numeros que quieras una o mas veces separado por comas.
Ejemplo: 2.20, 12.30, 34.40...y asi sucesivamente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu expresión `/^([0-9]+.([0-9]{2}))$/g` es válida solo para una cifra con dos decimales y sobra la bandera global (`g`), porque ya estás indicando que comience a buscar desde el inicio de la cadena (`^`) hasta el final (`$`).

Te sugiero simplificar un poco:

- Reemplaza `[0-9]` por `\d`, que son equivalentes
- Por legibilidad, agrupa solo cuando sea necesario (uso de paréntesis)

Explicando a detalle:

- `^`: Buscar desde el inicio de la cadena
- `\d+\.\d{2}`: Uno o más dígitos, seguidos de un punto y dos decimales
- `(`: Agrupar para poder hacer opcional

  - `\,`: La coma es obligatoria
  - `\d+\.\d{2}`: Se debe repetir el patrón para cada cifra adicional
- `)`: Fin de grupo
- `{0,}`: Cero o más cifras adicionales precedidas por coma. El cero es lo que hace que este grupo sea opcional
- `$`: Realizar la búsqueda hasta el fin de la cadena

```js
let regEx = /^\d+\.\d{2}(\,\d+\.\d{2}){0,}$/;

console.log(regEx.test('123.45'));  // Verdadero
console.log(regEx.test('123.456,')); // Falso, tres posiciones decimales
console.log(regEx.test('123.45,')); // Falso, no debe terminar con coma
// Verdaderos, cifras con dos decimales y separadas por coma
console.log(regEx.test('123.45,67.89'));
console.log(regEx.test('123.45,67.89,98.76,543.21,0.15'));
```

**Nota:** No soy experto en expresiones regulares, sigo aprendiendo, por lo que podría haber mejores formas de lograr tu objetivo.

Answer (score 0):

Con un "(" al inicio y ",?)+", lo arreglas, si te he entendido bien, claro.
`^(([0-9]+\.([0-9]{2}))\,?)+$`
[image: regexp (([0-9]+.([0-9]{2})),?)+]